# Python 3: check that command runs without exception in "if .. else" block without using "try .. except"

Tags: python, if-statement, exception

Is there any *native* language construction in Python 3 to check if some line of code can be run without exception without using "try .. except" block?

E. g.: I parse a list of files and need to select only those files that start with UNIX-date and "_" symbol to and pass them to another module. I don't need neither the result of conversion at the moment, nor the type of exception nor the text of exception, only the fact that this file suites the requirements:

```
FileList = ["1550889019_FileName1.tar", "New_document.doc", "1550000000_FileName2.7z", "Song.mp3"] 
ValidFiles = []
for FileName in FileList:
    # Cut everything after first '_' symbol, convert to integer and try to parse as a date
    if no_exception(datetime.date.fromtimestamp(int(re.sub(r'_.*$', '', FileName)))):
        ValidFiles.append(FileName)

DoSmth(ValidFiles)
```

P. S.: I know that I can declare "no_exception()" function, run the code inside a "try .. except" block there and return false on exception, but I search for native "more elegant" solution right now.

Comment: Try / except would be the elegant solution IMO.

Comment: Why do you not want to use try/except?

Comment: No, other languages have constructions like that because exceptions are expansive. Python does not because it is designed to handle exceptions efficiently. (that's why recursion is so bad in python) The proper way to see if something throws an exception in python is simply to handle the exception. Although you can do that inside a function called no_exception which returns a bool.

Comment: "Why do you not want to use try/except?" Because I thought that it could save me a few lines of code for better readability. This is not critical, of course.